# Python library to add editable text box in a PDF file

Tags: python, pdf

I need to add the following text: "Hello World!" in a PDF file using Python and then be able to edit it from the PDF reader.
Basically I need a Python script that opens a PDF file and then adds the editable text. Then I should also be able to edit the sentence in Adobe Reader (or a generic pdf reader) from "Hello World!" to "Hello Jim!"

I have tried many libraries like `pikepdf`, `reportlab`, `pypdf`, `PyPDF2`, `pdfrw`, etc, but I have not found what I need.

For example with this code I'm able to add text in the PDF file:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

pdf = canvas.Canvas("s_pii_pdf_fac_simile_Copy.pdf")

pdf.drawString(x = 300, y = 400, text = "Hello World!", mode = None, charSpace = 2, direction = None, wordSpace = None)
```

But, once I open the PDF file from Adobe Reader, I can't edit the text.

Another example is this:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

text = "input.pdf"

pdf = canvas.Canvas(text)

pdf.drawCentredString(100, 0, "blablabla")
x = pdf.acroForm
x.textfield(fillColor = colors.yellow, borderColor = colors.black, textColor = colors.red, borderWidth = 2, borderStyle = 'solid', width = 500, height = 50, x = 50, y = 40, tooltip = None, name = None, fontSize = 20)
```

Here I'm able to add an editable box when I open the PDF file with Adobe reader, but the box is empty and I need to manually add text in it via Adobe reader. In this case I would need to prepopulate the box with the "hello world!" string and be able to edit the text inside the box from Adobe reader:

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Thank you @KJ for your answer. I have edited the question to be more clear and added another example. Basically I use the acroForm to add a text box, but I need to pre-populate the box in order to see the box with the text inside of it when I open the file with Adobe reader.

Comment: You could try [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) and add a free text annotation to it. Documentation [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.add_freetext_annot).

Comment: I solved this issue, basically I simply needed to add the <value = "Hello World!">, before the fillColor parameter inside the x.textfield() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the solution to this problem was easier than expected.
All I need to do to add text inside the box via Python is to change the line where I specify `.textfield()` from this:

```
x.textfield(fillColor = colors.yellow, borderColor = colors.black, textColor = colors.red, borderWidth = 2, borderStyle = 'solid', width = 500, height = 50, x = 50, y = 40, tooltip = None, name = None, fontSize = 20)
```

to this:

```
x.textfield(value = "Hello World!", fillColor = colors.yellow, borderColor = colors.black, textColor = colors.red, borderWidth = 2, borderStyle = 'solid', width = 500, height = 50, x = 50, y = 40, tooltip = None, name = None, fontSize = 20)
```

What I obtain is what I wanted:

[image: editable text box]

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.

Let's start by creating a basic PDF with a `FormField`:

```py
#!chapter_004/src/snippet_001.py
from decimal import Decimal

from borb.pdf import TextField
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import FixedColumnWidthTable
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # create Document
    doc: Document = Document()

    # create Page
    page: Page = Page()

    # add Page to Document
    doc.add_page(page)

    # set a PageLayout:
    # using a PageLayout means you don't need to worry about
    # the exact locations of content
    # kind of like how Microsoft Word works.
    layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    # add FixedColumnWidthTable containing Paragraph and TextField objects
    # FixedColumnWidthTable is an implementation of Table
    # that is designed to take up the full width of the Page
    # and divide that width evenly among its columns
    layout.add(
        FixedColumnWidthTable(number_of_columns=2, number_of_rows=3)
        .add(Paragraph("Name:"))
        .add(TextField(field_name="name"))
        .add(Paragraph("Firstname:"))
        .add(TextField(field_name="firstname"))
        .add(Paragraph("Country"))
        # add TextField already pre-filled with 'Belgium'
        .add(TextField(field_name="country", value="Belgium"))
        .set_padding_on_all_cells(Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2), Decimal(2))
        .no_borders()
    )

    # store
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That would give us the following PDF:

[image: a PDF created by borb with a pre-filled TextField]

`borb` can be obtained using `pip` or from source on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Joris! Is there a way to add the boxes you have created with your script in an already existing pdf file instead of creating a new pdf file? Also I need to locate the box based on the x-y coordinates (specified in centimeters) of the pdf page.

Comment: Of course, you can read an existing PDF and simply add content (including forms) to it. You can use a PageLayout (which does the layout for you) but you can also call the `paint` method (passing it a Page object, and a bounding box)

Comment: And with this method will I have the possibility to edit the text inside the box and location of the box from the pdf editor?

Comment: The solution I provided is a complete code sample. You can simply copy/paste it, run it, and see whether it works in the PDF editor/viewer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not specifically Python you could use OS shell commands so using [pdfcpu](https://github.com/pdfcpu) 1 2 3

- Image on the Left was a command line generated out.pdf for 2 pages as 1 (3&4 are now page2)
- Image in center was one line shell command so as to overlay the demo English form structure (you prepare similar in JSON)

```
pdfcpu create english.json out.pdf output.pdf
reading out.pdf...
writing output.pdf...
```

- Image on right is the form edits in Acrobat (yes, it's visually a mess, but shows overwriting)

[image]

To pre-populate with `Hello World!` just set it as default

[image]

```
    "pages": {
        "1": {
            "content": {
                "textfield": [
                    {
                        "hide": false,
                        "id": "firstName1",
                        "tip": "First Name",
                        "tab": 1,
                        "default": "Hello World!",
                        "pos": [
                            120,
                            665
                        ],
                        "width": 200,
                        "align": "left",
                        "border": {
                            "width":1,
                            "col": "Gray"
                        },
                        "label": {
                            "value": "First Name:",
                            "width": 80,
                            "gap": 10,
                            "align": "left",
                            "pos": "left"
                        }
                    },
```

And because they are Standard FDF entries you can export and import as paired text values for bulk processing

```
>> 
<< /T (firstName1) /V (Hello Jim!) >>
<< /T (gender1) /V /male >>
<< /T (lastName1) /V (Doe) >>
<< /T (dob1) /V (31.12.1999)>>
<< /T (note1) /V (This is a sample text.\nThis is the next line.) >>
<< /T (firstName2) /V (Jackie) >>
<< /T (lastName2) /V (Doe) >>
<< /T (gender2) /V /non-binary >>
<< /T (note2) /V (This is a sample text.\nThis is the next line.) >>
<< /T (dob2) /V (31.12.1999) >>
]
/ID [<873C2E88D945FE06938025CB639EC603> <7600FA02F3E4480081C3473E330197CA>]
/UF (JimDoe.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
```

[image]